# Can someone clarify this graph presentation for me?

Tags: graph

I have a presentation of solid, cycle free graph that forms as follows:

- Remove vertices which has a degree of 1 (has only one edge) one by one
- If there is more than one opinion, vertex with the lowest value will be removed
- When vertex is removed, the vertex next to it will me marked
- This will go on until graph has only one vertex left

Here's an example:

```
   

    2   3            3
     \ /            /
  5   1    =>  5   1   =>   5   1  =>   5    =>  5
   \ /          \ /          \ /        \
    4            4            4         4
```

The presentation is:

```
1 1 4 5
```

How can I turn this presentation into f.e. following matrix:

```
   1  2  3  4  5 
-----------------
1  0  1  1  1  0
-----------------
2  1  0  0  0  0
-----------------
3  1  0  0  0  0
-----------------
4  1  0  0  0  1
-----------------
5  0  0  0  1  0
-----------------
```

I've been struggling with this for a while now, so if anyone can help, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the matrix:

```
   1  2  3  4  5 
-----------------
1  0  1  1  1  0
-----------------
2  1  0  0  0  0
-----------------
3  1  0  0  0  0
-----------------
4  1  0  0  0  1
-----------------
5  0  0  0  1  0
-----------------
```

is just the adjacency matrix of the original graph.